# Is there an issue with opening filenames provided on the command line through $_?

Tags: perl, file-io

I'm having trouble modifying a script that processes files passed as command line arguments, merely for copying those files, to additionally modifying those files.  The following perl script worked just fine for copying files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy;

foreach $_ (@ARGV) {
   my $orig = $_;
   (my $copy = $orig) =~ s/\.js$/_extjs4\.js/;
   copy($orig, $copy) or die(qq{failed to copy $orig -> $copy});
}
```

Now that I have files named "*_extjs4.js", I would like to pass those into a script that similarly takes file names from the command line, and further processes the lines within those files.  So far I am able get a file handle successfully as the following script and it's output shows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach $_ (@ARGV) {
    print "$_\n";
    open(my $fh, "+>", $_) or die $!;
    print $fh;
    #while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    #    print $line;
    #}
    close $fh;
}
```

Which outputs (in part):

```
./filetree_extjs4.js
GLOB(0x1a457de8)
./async_submit_extjs4.js
GLOB(0x1a457de8)
```

*What I really want to do though rather than printing a representation of the file handle, is to work with the contents of the files themselves.*  A start would be to print the files lines, which I've tried to do with the commented out code above.

But that code has no effect, the files' lines do not get printed.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a conflict between the $_ used to process command line arguments, and the one used to process file contents?

Comment: +1 : This is a very good question. Attempt shown, problem explained and  end goal stated very clearly.

Comment: Whoever edited the question title, good job, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple of questions here.

---

***What I really want to do though rather than printing a representation of the file handle, is to work with the contents of the files themselves.***

The reason why `print $fh` is returning `GLOB(0x1a457de8)` is because the scalar `$fh` is a filehandle and not the contents of the file itself. To access the contents of the file itself,  use `<$fh>`. For example:

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    print $line;
}

# or simply print while <$fh>;
```

will print the contents of the entire file.

This is documented in [`pelrdoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators):

> If what the angle brackets contain is a simple scalar variable (e.g.,
>   `<$foo>`), then that variable contains the name of the filehandle to
>   input from, or its typeglob, or a reference to the same.

---

***But it has already been tried!***

I can see that. Try it after changing the open mode to `+<`.

According to [`perldoc perlfaq5`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-come-when-I-open-a-file-read-write-it-wipes-it-out%3f):

> #### How come when I open a file read-write it wipes it out?
>
> Because you're using something like this, which truncates the file
>   then gives you read-write access:
>
> ```
>   open my $fh, '+>', '/path/name'; # WRONG (almost always)
> ```
>
> Whoops. You should instead use this, which will fail if the file
>   doesn't exist:
>
> ```
>   open my $fh, '+<', '/path/name'; # open for update
> ```
>
> Using `">"` always clobbers or creates. Using `"<"` never does either. The
>   `"+"` doesn't change this.

It goes without saying that the `or die $!` after the `open` is highly recommended.

---

***But take a step back.***

There is a more Perlish way to back up the original file and subsequently manipulate it. In fact, it is doable via the command line itself (!) using the `-i` flag:

```
$ perl -p -i._extjs4 -e 's/foo/bar/g' *.js
```

See [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for more details.

---

***I can't fit my needs into the command-line.***

If the manipulation is too much for the command-line to handle, the [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) module is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see that none of my files have content anymore because of the way I opened the file.  This makes me glad I made the first script for copying the files reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

To read the contents of a filehandle you have to call [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) [`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) or place the filehandle in angle brackets [`<>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators).

```
my $line = readline $fh;
my $actually_read = read $fh, $text, $bytes;
my $line = <$fh>; # similar to readline
```

---

To print to a filehandle other than `STDIN` you have to have it as the first argument to [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html), followed by what you want to print, without a comma between them.

```
print $fh 'something';
```

To prevent someone from accidentally adding a comma, I prefer to put the filehandle in a block.

```
print {$fh} 'something';
```

You could also [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) your new handle.

```
{
  my $oldfh = select $fh;
  print 'something';
  select $oldfh; # reset it back to the previous handle
}
```

---

Also your mode argument to [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), causes it to clobber the contents of the file. At which point there is nothing left to read.

Try this instead:

```
open my $fh, '+<', $_ or die;
```

Comment: I just added emphasis to the following line in my question: "What I really want to do though rather than printing a representation of the file handle, is to work with the contents of the files themselves."

Comment: @GeorgeJempty added [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) [`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) and [`<>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators). Really you should be reading the [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org).

Comment: Of course I am reading online material, including the documentation.  StackOverflow, unlike comp.lang.perl.misc, is not an appropriate forum for RTFM style comments.  Looking at one of the commented out lines in my code you will see I was using <>.  Without testing your suggestion(s) this leads me to believe that your suggestion as to how to use open is where I was going wrong, though I found an example online and *thought* I understood it.

Comment: [builder@george v6.5 javascript]$ find . -name "*_extjs4.js" | xargs ./replace_ext_extend_ext_define.pl
./filetree_extjs4.js
Invalid separator character '+' in PerlIO layer specification + at ./replace_ext_extend_ext_define.pl line 9.
Unknown open() mode '<+' at ./replace_ext_extend_ext_define.pl line 9.

Comment: "<$fh>" is not merely "similar to" "readline $fh". They are exactly equivalent. i.e. they are 2 different ways of writing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add something to Zaid's excellent suggestion of using a one-liner.

When you are new to perl, and trying some tricky regexes, it can be nice to use a source file for them, as the command line may get rather crowded. I.e.:

**The file:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

s/complicated/regex/g;
```

While tweaking the regex, use the source file like so:

```
perl -p script.pl input.js
perl -p script.pl input.js > testfile
perl -p script.pl input.js | less
```

Note that you don't use the `-i` flag here while testing. These commands will not change the input files, only print the changes to stdout.

When you're ready to execute the (permanent!) changes, just add the in-place edit `-i` flag, and if you wish (recommended), supply an extension for backups, e.g. ".bak".

```
perl -pi.bak script.pl *.js
```